# this.$refs.myForm.validate is not a function in my vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js, ref

The rules work and display the correct validation messages.
The button is disabled when this.valid is false.
The checkTextBoxValidation method is called with every input to check validation in the myForm ref.
and once it tries to validate I get the error in the title. therefore this.valid doesn't change.

```
      checkTextBoxValidation() {
        console.log('check v-text-box validation');
        this.valid = !!(this.$refs.myForm as Vue & {
          validate: () => Promise<boolean>
        }).validate();
        console.log('valid:', this.valid);
      },
```

```
              <v-form ref='myForm' @submit.prevent='submit(idx, fpIdx)'>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col sm='7'>
                    <v-text-field label='Enter Value'
                                  v-model='subHeader.updateAmount'
                                  :rules='[...rules.currencyValue, ...rules.required]'
                                  required
                                  @input='checkTextBoxValidation'
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col sm='5' class='mt-2'>
                    <v-btn rounded
                           color='primary'
                           type='submit'
                           :disabled='!valid'
                    >{{ SUBMIT_LABEL }}
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-form>
```

I've also tried
`this.valid = (this.$refs.myForm as HTMLFormElement).checkValidity();` 
and get
this.$refs.myForm.checkValidity is not a function

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AlexGill this.$refs.myForm.validate is not a function

Comment: ($refs.myForm.validate as HTMLFormElement).validate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when I put your code into a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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), so my guess is that your error happens somewhere else. Are you running the function from somewhere else before the component is mounted?

---

Note that `.verify()` returns a promise, so `!!this.$refs.myForm.validate()` will always be true (since the promise it not a falsy value).

---

All in all, you might be better of by just binding to the `modelValue` of VForm:

```
<v-form @update:modelValue="isValid => valid = isValid || isValid === null">
```

(note that the value returned from update will be null if the form is valid but the [validate-on](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props-validate-on) event has not happened yet)

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding  @update:modelValue="input.modelValue = $event" to the v-text-box and the isValid v-model worked. Your playground helped immensely.

Comment: this.validationResult = await !!(this.$refs.myForm as Vue & {
          validate: () => Promise<boolean>
        }).validate();

I used this for the validationResult